# How to create number list 1 until 9 and plus 1 at another row in php?

Tags: php

How to create number list in php 1 until 9 with this out put 

**1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9**

**2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1**

**3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2**

**4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3**

**5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4**

**6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5**

**7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6**

**8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7**

**9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8**

Please Let me know ...

Comment: Looks like an assignment of some sort

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share the code you currently have?

Comment: https://eval.in/813718

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one that accepts a variable number of rows and columns:

```
<?php
$rows = 9;
$cols = 9;
for ($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++) {
  $num = ($row % $cols);
  for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
      if (++$num == $cols + 1) {
          $num = 1;
      }
      echo $num . ' ';
  }
  echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 <?php

    for( $i = 1; $i<10; $i++ ) {
       $count=$i;
       for($j=1;$j<10;$j++){
             echo($count);

             if($count==9)
                 {$count=0;}
             $count++;

         }
         echo('<br>');
      }

      ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry....I like being fancy:

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    foreach($array as &$item)
        echo ($item >= 10 ? $item++ - 9 : $item++), ' ';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

or

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

do {
    echo implode(' ', $array), '<br>';
} while(($array[] = $array[0]) && array_shift($array) && $array[0] != 1);
```

Comment: How can i read this **echo ($item >= 10 ? $item++ - 9 : $item++), ' ';** ??